# Uber Promo Codes: Intended User Experience

Tags: uber-api

I’m trying to get some basic information about how promo codes work with Uber.

- If we are building a mobile app and want to supply a promo code to users, is there a method through which we can apply the promo code to their account without them having to type it in? (e.g. we provide a deep link/URL/button that allows the user to apply the code to their account)
- Is there a website that is created for a given promo code that allows users to do this process? We've noted that Lyft creates a specific site we can direct users to where they input their phone number to either apply or sign up for Lyft. Wondering if Uber has similar functionality.
- What is the preferred user experience for promo codes when that code is being distributed through our mobile app?

Comment: In regards to your first question, yes, you can provide a deeplink that auto inputs a promo code: https://developer.uber.com/products/ride-requests-deeplink

I'm not sure exactly about your next two questions.

Comment: @KyleDavis: conceptually, I don't quite understand promo codes. For Lyft, the promo code is applied to the user's account once; when the user goes to plan a trip, if they meet the conditions of the promo code, it is automatically applied to the trip, and there is therefore no need to pass the promo code in the deep link, since it already exists through a separate process along with that user. For Uber, if we include a promo code in the deep link, will it ignore the promo code if it no longer applies?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.